# Post and Pre Increment in C

Tags: c

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Could anyone explain these undefined behaviors (i = i++ + ++i , i = i++, etc…)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/949433/could-anyone-explain-these-undefined-behaviors-i-i-i-i-i-etc)

There is a code following below and i ma facing a very serious problem in understanding the logic for the code.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void )
{
int i = 1 ;
printf("\n%d %d %d %d\n",++i,i++,i++,++i) ;
return 0 ;
}
```

I am using gcc compiler under the linux distro named Mandriva. In the above mentioned i have used pre and post increment with a variable in the printf statement. 
The output that i am supposed to get is 2 2 3 5, but i am getting a different output. 
Please help me in this code.

I am feeling much difficult in this code.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's undefined behavior. There's no sequence points between the increments of `i`.

Any result is a correct result (including your hard drive being formatted).

Comment: The hard drive being formatted is not a valid result of this code. It is only undefined regarding the evaluation order.

Comment: Does it really matter for integers if we do `++i` or `i++`? I thought this is the same. It only differs when we post-increment or pre-increment an object.. then in the first case it is modified and evaluated and in the second case it is copied and then modified. What am I missing?

Comment: K Grigore. But is this undefined behaviour because of the version of the compiler or with the version of the OS distro we were using? What is the compiler that i can depend on? Is there any chances that we can  change the behaviour of the compiler?

Comment: @Raj89 no you can't. It's undefined because the standard says it's undefined. Just don't do it.

Comment: And also what does formatting the hard drives has to do with the result? Please tell me clearly.

Comment: @Raj89 undefined behavior means *anything* can happen. The "format your hard drive" was a joke (although theoretically, it could happen)

Comment: K Grigore. I understand. Thanks anyway. Another thing. Does this same code vary compiler to compiler?

Comment: @Raj89 you don't seem to understand. The code isn't guaranteed to give the same result every time even on the same compiler.

Comment: S... I understand that Grigore. But there are variety of compilers and does that variety of compilers gall share the same undefined behaviour?

Comment: @Raj89 yes. Undefined behavior is part of the language, it doesn't care what compiler you use.

Comment: @LuchianGrigore : I was thinking about the same program. how would you determine it is an undefined behaviour???